# RSA public key to base64 String

Tags: java, python, cryptography, base64, rsa

I have written a socket server. The server-side is Java and the client-side is in Python. The server uses TCP communication and since TCP is not safe I use asymmetric encryption. The server has a private-public key pair and every time a client connects it sends the public key and requests clients public key.

In order to send the `PublicKey` object over TCP, I convert it to string with this function.

```java
public String publicKeyToString(PublicKey publicKey){
    byte[] pKBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();  // Get the public key to bytes

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pKBytes);  // Convert the public key to String
}
```

On the other side to create a `PublicKey` object from string I use this function

```java
public PublicKey publicKeyFromString(String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

The above code works very well with java clients. Now I would like to do the same thing in python. I create the private-public key with this block of code

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

client_private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

client_public_key = client_private_key.public_key()
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to extract a string from the public key so I can send it to the server. Also, the string key will be decoded from `public String publicKeyToString(PublicKey publicKey)` so it should be encoded with base64.

"Specs":

1. Java 8 with java.security library
2. Python 3 with cryptography library
3. Encryption algorithm RSA

If you have a better library for python I am open to suggestions, java is somewhat fixed because by this point to much code is written.

Comment: "*Any help would be appreciated."* - Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*If you have a better library...*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I am not asking you to recommend a library all I am saying is that If you know how to solve the problem using a certain library I can change my initial one (cryptography in this case). Also, the question of the post is very clear both from the title and the post itself "How to convert python public key to base64 string". Any help would be appreciated goes to anyone that will point me to an article or something else instead of providing a direct solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use TLS to secure your socket connections instead of rolling your own crypto?

Comment: You can serialize the key in different formats and encodings, e.g. for the public key, see [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-serialization), 3rd code snippet, which serializes the public key as PEM encoded X.509 key (`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----...`). With `format=serialization.PublicFormat.PKCS1` the PKCS#1 format is defined, with `encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER` the DER encoding. This allows the key to be formatted in the same way as the Java code does: X.509 format, DER encoded, Base64 encoded.

Comment: @Topaco Why the PKCS#1 remark? The SubjectPublicKeyInfo encoding is what Java uses, so the code snippet is OK. Indeed, then output as DER and base64 encode...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Just an explanation of the options. The relevant parameters used in the Java code are summarized at the end of my comment.